# Filling an M x N rectangle with squares with sides of lengths 2^K, 2^(K - 1), ..., 4, 2, 1

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

We are given an *M x N* rectangle and asked to fill it with squares with sides of lengths *2^K, 2^(K - 1), ..., 4, 2, 1*. We first fill with *2^K* (as much as we can), then with *2^(K - 1)*, and so on. How many squares are we going to need in total?

I wrote the following recursive code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long_pow(long base, long exponent)
{
    if (!exponent)
        return 1L;

    return base * long_pow(base, exponent - 1L);
}

long cover(long width, long height, long side)
{
    if (width <= 0L || height <= 0L)
        return 0L;

    long full_width = width / side;   // The full width we can cover.
    long full_height = height / side; // The full height we can cover.

    return (full_width * full_height) // The full area we can cover
                                      // plus the rest (recursively).
           + cover(width - full_width * side, height, side / 2L)
           + cover(full_width * side, height - full_height * side, side / 2L);
}

int main()
{
    long width, height, k;
    scanf("%ld %ld %ld", &width, &height, &k);
    printf("%ld\n", cover(width, height, long_pow(2L, k)));
    return 0;
}
```

This code fails on 1 of the 10 test cases I was given. Namely, on `123456789 987654321 4`, it outputs `1690311532` instead of `476300678536044`. However, on `123456789 987654321 30` it outputs the correct result of `1437797319`. Other test cases work well, too.

Where could the problem be?

Comment: I ran it and it gave me correct results for the `123456789 987654321 4` test case, i.e.: `476300678536044`.

Comment: @REACHUS: Thanks a lot. The problem was that `long` was not... long enough on my system. Replacing everything with `uint64_t` did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with the code was that `long` was overflowing.  I used `unit64_t` instead.